# numpad in tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to link a numpad to the entry field in my Python code, but i cant get it working. I hope someone can help me with this. Thanks in advance!

**My code**

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk
from PIL.ImageTk import PhotoImage
from tkinter import Button


# background

FILENAME = 'C:\Volledig Project\Sealapparaat-800x480.jpg'
root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=800, height=480)
canvas.pack()
tk_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=FILENAME)
canvas.create_image(400, 240, image=tk_img)


entry1 = tk.Entry(root)
entr1_windows = canvas.create_window(30, 300, anchor="nw", window=entry1)

muted3 = False


def mute_picture():
    global muted3
    if muted3:
        volumeKnop3.configure(image=volumePhoto3)
        muted3 = False
        root.after(int(entry1.get()), mute_picture)
    else:
        volumeKnop3.configure(image=mutePhoto3)
        muted3 = True

root.after(0, mute_picture)


mutePhoto3 = PhotoImage(file="C:\Volledig Project\Time_Done.png")
volumePhoto3 = PhotoImage(file="C:\Volledig Project\Time_Not_Done.png")

volumeKnop3 = Button(image=volumePhoto3, command=mute_picture, background="white", activebackground="White", border=0)
volumeKnop3_window = canvas.create_window(30, 200, anchor="nw", window=volumeKnop3)

root.mainloop()
```

*i have found and tried several numpads but i cant get one working so i hope somebody has a good numpad and knows how i can implement it in my code*

Comment: "but i cant get it working"  what is not working? Please follow the recommendations here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What does any of this code have to do with a numpad?

Answer (score 1):

This was a numpad example I wrote a few years ago for a Raspberry Pi touch screen application. It works (I could improve upon the code now though).

Click on an entry field to bring up the Numpad. To make it work in your code, replace your `entry1` instance of `tk.Entry` with my `NumpadEntry`. Should be as simple as that.
For example

```
entry1 = NumpadEntry(root)
```

EDIT: Slight change made to add the `enumerate_row_column` generator. Old way of doing it wasn't very pythonic.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import simpledialog

def enumerate_row_column(iterable, num_cols):
    for idx, item in enumerate(iterable):
        row = idx // num_cols
        col = idx % num_cols
        yield row,col,item

class NumpadEntry(Entry):
    def __init__(self,parent=None,**kw):
        Entry.__init__(self,parent,**kw)
        self.bind('<FocusIn>',self.numpadEntry)
        self.bind('<FocusOut>',self.numpadExit)
        self.edited = False
    def numpadEntry(self,event):
        if self.edited == False:
            print("You Clicked on me")
            self['bg']= '#ffffcc'
            self.edited = True
            new = numPad(self)
        else:
            self.edited = False
    def numpadExit(self,event):
        self['bg']= '#ffffff'

class numPad(simpledialog.Dialog):
    def __init__(self,master=None,textVariable=None):
        self.top = Toplevel(master=master)
        self.top.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",self.ok)
        self.createWidgets()
        self.master = master
        
    def createWidgets(self):
        btn_list = ['7',  '8',  '9', '4',  '5',  '6', '1',  '2',  '3', '0',  'Close',  'Del']
        # create and position all buttons with a for-loop
        btn = []
        # Use custom generator to give us row/column positions
        for r,c,label in enumerate_row_column(btn_list,3):
            # partial takes care of function and argument
            cmd = lambda x = label: self.click(x)
            # create the button
            cur = Button(self.top, text=label, width=10, height=5, command=cmd)
            # position the button
            cur.grid(row=r, column=c)                                              
            btn.append(cur)
            
    def click(self,label):
        print(label)
        if label == 'Del':
            currentText = self.master.get()
            self.master.delete(0, END)
            self.master.insert(0, currentText[:-1])
        elif label == 'Close':
            self.ok()
        else:
            currentText = self.master.get()
            self.master.delete(0, END)
            self.master.insert(0, currentText+label)
    def ok(self):
        self.top.destroy()
        self.top.master.focus()

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent=None,**kw):
        Frame.__init__(self,parent,**kw)
        self.textEntryVar1 = StringVar()
        self.e1 = NumpadEntry(self,textvariable=self.textEntryVar1)
        self.e1.grid()

        self.textEntryVar2 = StringVar()
        self.e2 = NumpadEntry(self,textvariable=self.textEntryVar2)
        self.e2.grid()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("200x100")
    app = App(root)
    app.grid()
    root.mainloop()
```