# Python: Tkinter buttons aren't appearing

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm relatively new to tkinter python (3.9.0) and I'm trying to create a scientific calculator, but for some reason, the numberpad buttons won't show up when I try to run the code - it only shows me the text diplay. I was wandering if somebody could figure out what I've done wrong. I kinda need to find out quickly.

Code:

```
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()
root.title("Calculator")
root.config(background ="LightGoldenRod")
root.resizable()
root.geometry("480x568+0+0")

calc = Frame(root)

#Numberpad not working**
numberpad = "789456123"
i = 0
btn = []
for j in range(2,5):
    for k in range(3):
        btn.append(Button(calc, width=6, height=2, font=("arial",20,"bold"), bd=4, text=numberpad[i]))
        btn[i].grid(row=j, column=k, pady=1)
        i += 1

#Display
textDisplay = Entry(font=('arial', 20,'bold'), bd=30, width=28, bg="LightGoldenRod", justify='right')
textDisplay.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4, pady=1)
textDisplay.insert(0,"0")


#Menus & Operations
def iExit():
    iExit = messagebox.askyesno("Calculator", "Confirm if you want to exit")
    if iExit > 0:
        root.destroy()
        return 
    
def Scientific():
    root.resizable()
    root.geometry("944x568+0+0")

def Default():
    root.resizable()
    root.geometry("480x568+0+0")
    
menubar = Menu(root)

filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
filemenu.add_command(label="Default", command=Default)
filemenu.add_command(label="Scientific", command=Scientific)
filemenu.add_separator()
filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=iExit)

editmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=editmenu)
editmenu.add_command(label="Cut", command=lambda:print('Cut'))
editmenu.add_command(label="Copy", command=lambda:print('Copy'))
editmenu.add_separator()
editmenu.add_command(label="Paste", command=lambda:print('Paste'))

helpmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpmenu)
helpmenu.add_command(label="View", command=lambda:print('Cut'))

root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: you are not iterating through **numberpad** so **text=numberpad[i]** is not functional , you should add **for i in numberpad**

Comment: You need to call `calc.grid()` after `textDisplay.insert(...)`.

Comment: You might find this answer helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63914121/numpad-in-tkinter-python/63915544#63915544 The numpad is currently in a seperate dialog but could easily be adapted to be inside a frame inside your application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had not ran the grid method on your frame. I went ahead and added some additional code that is by no means complete but will help you get further along.

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from functools import partial  # imported partial to help make the command necessary for dynamic button creation

root = Tk()
root.title("Calculator")
root.config(background="LightGoldenRod")
root.resizable()
root.geometry("480x568+0+0")

calc = Frame(root)
textDisplay = Entry(font=('arial', 20, 'bold'), bd=30, width=28, bg="LightGoldenRod", justify='right')
insert_cursor = 0


def insert_num(num):
    global insert_cursor
    textDisplay.insert(insert_cursor, num)
    insert_cursor += 1


# Numberpad not working**
numberpad = [7, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]  # you can use an int to avoid having to use type conversions
i = 0
btn = []
for j in range(2, 5):
    for k in range(3):
        btn.append(Button(calc, width=6, height=2, font=("arial", 20, "bold"), bd=4, text=numberpad[i], command=partial(insert_num, numberpad[i])))
        btn[i].grid(row=j, column=k, pady=1)
        i += 1

# Display

textDisplay.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4, pady=1)
textDisplay.insert(0, 0)
calc.grid(row=1, columnspan=4)  # you never grid your frame

# Menus & Operations
def iExit():
    iExit = messagebox.askyesno("Calculator", "Confirm if you want to exit")
    if iExit > 0:
        root.destroy()
        return


def Scientific():
    root.resizable()
    root.geometry("944x568+0+0")


def Default():
    root.resizable()
    root.geometry("480x568+0+0")


menubar = Menu(root)

filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
filemenu.add_command(label="Default", command=Default)
filemenu.add_command(label="Scientific", command=Scientific)
filemenu.add_separator()
filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=iExit)

editmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=editmenu)
editmenu.add_command(label="Cut", command=lambda: print('Cut'))
editmenu.add_command(label="Copy", command=lambda: print('Copy'))
editmenu.add_separator()
editmenu.add_command(label="Paste", command=lambda: print('Paste'))

helpmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpmenu)
helpmenu.add_command(label="View", command=lambda: print('Cut'))

root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```